# Jquery Validation Engine Error Messages and eric martin modal window

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, simplemodal

I am using jquery validation engine in modal window. But error messages corresponding to the modal window are attached with the main form. when i am scrolling the main form, modal window's error messages are also scrolling with the form but it should not.It should scroll with the modal window form.
I have tried 'overflown' attribute and 'auto position update' attribute.But these working fine with the main form only not with the modal window.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried position attribute as "relative" or "fixed" for your error message box?

The non scrolling box should use this position attribute to actually fix the x,y position values for whole window!

try that and let me know the results!

Comment: I tried both position attributes..but these are not working.And my modal window is also scrolling. i want to scroll the error messages with the modal window scroller instead of main window scroller.

Comment: I am using these two plugins: 1)For validation : http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/ 2)For Modal Window : http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

Comment: Can you post the link to your actual code so that I can review your implementation as the link you sent me is obviously working fine! as it doesn't have any other css component which may create a conflict for existing css of validation boxes! Also have you tried to check any sort of overrides on css using firebug or similar tools?

Comment: Sorry i can't share that link.It is not a public website it is a client's internal site so you can't access it. Yes, I tried to debug it from firebug but didn't get anything